# Problem in xcode

Tags: objective-c, opencv

I having problem in the xcode and its show the error .
But I build it is success but its show me these error 
**Theard 2 :program received signal : " SIGABRT ".**    at these sentences

**CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad([path cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], NULL, NULL, NULL);**

THANK IN ADVANCE

```
// Load XML
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"haarcascade_frontalface_default" ofType:@"xml"];//@"haarcascade_frontalface_default" ofType:@"xml"];
CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad([path cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], NULL, NULL, NULL); // <-- here
CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
```

Comment: what does cvLoad do and what is the value of path?

Answer (score 0):

SIGABRT generally means an exception was thrown. Read your logs; it will likely tell you what the exception was.

Do not use `cStringUsingEncoding:` on a path. Use `[path UTF8String]`. Mac and iOS use UTF-8 for just about everything. ASCII is increasingly rare. It just happens to be equivalent in many but not all cases.

Verify that `path` is not `nil`. If you mis-typed the file name, then `path` will be nil, and cvLoad probably crashes in that case.

Comment: I have change to the cStringUsingEncoding: to path UTF8String .

Comment: I have change to the cStringUsingEncoding: to path UTF8String . I still having this problem "  Theard 2 :program received signal : " SIGABRT "  "

or I done wrong for the changing part .

CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad([path UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);

Thank in advance ..

Comment: Re-read your logs. There are generally error messages before the SIGABRT.